# AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome'

Tags: python, selenium

Использую selenium + python. Установил selenium в python через pip и написал такой код :

```
from selenium import webdriver    
driver=webdriver.Chrome("E:\drivers\chromedriver.exe")
```

При выполнении в Pycharm появвляется такой лог с ошибкой :

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File"C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/untitled/bot.py", line 3, in <module> 
driver=webdriver.Chrome("E:\drivers\chromedriver.exe") 
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome'
```

А при выполнении через IDLE :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\untitled\bot.py", line 3, in <module>
driver=webdriver.Chrome("E:\drivers\chromedriver.exe")
File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py",     
line 75, in __init__desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",     
line 154, in __init__self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",     
line 243, in start_session response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", 
line 312, in execute self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", 
line 242, in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: 
Message: unknown error: chrome failed to start (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)`
```

Используется питон версии 3.6.4

Comment: для запуска Chrome помимо chromedriver нужно чтоб в системе был Google Chrome браузер, у вас он точно есть?

Comment: да, chrome установлен

Comment: Скачай версію Chromedriver 2.37 і попробуй запусти не через pycharm, а через термінал

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить seleneium в настройках venv Project Interpreter Selenium. Ctrl + Alt + S и добавьте его в списке. 
[image: Скрин с настройками]